# Parameters in bw2, what to use bw2data.parameters or bw2parameters?

Tags: brightway

I will need to import and work on few databases containing parameters in bw2, ecoinvent(s) and another db exported from Simapro. While in the past I had used bw2parameters I have seen now the handling of parameters has been also included in bwdata and I am getting a bit confused. what is the workflow now? should I just rely and work with one of the two, both or what? and with which version of the two packages?
thx

Answer (score 0):

Parameters (named variables and formulas stored as strings) are introduced in Brightway2-data version 3.0, which is currently a release candidate. Although we have [effectively 100% test coverage](https://coveralls.io/builds/14036704/source?filename=bw2data%2Fparameters.py) and [some documentation](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#parameterized-datasets), I would like to wait a bit before the final release to improve the documentation and make sure that there aren't any bugs that pop up somewhere. That being said, I would feel completely comfortable using the release candidate (along with [Brightway2-IO 0.6.RC3](https://anaconda.org/cmutel/bw2io), which provides nice ways to specify parameters).

`bw2parameters` is a library for evaluating a graph of variables and formulas. `bw2data` is a library for storing, loading, and exporting variables and formulas, tracking when their values are obsolete. They don't compete but instead work together.

Comment: so `bw2io` to import parameters and formulas (which are stored in `bw2data`) and `bw2parameters` to evaluate parameters and formulas